# Spivak Chapter 14 Problem 7: Clarification

Tags: calculus, analysis, definite-integrals

I would like to clarify what I'm being asked to prove in the following question from Spivak:
[image]

Am I being asked to find all continuous functions, such that this equality holds for all real numbers $x$? Or does this equality only need to hold for $1$, specific $x$, but that $x$ can be an arbitrary number?

Thanks in advance! Also, could you avoid giving hints to this problem, as I would like to give it a go myself first.

Comment: This probably need to hold for all $x$

Comment: @SolubleFish I see, thanks!